# Subquery - listing both courses

Tags: oracle, subquery

I am trying to provide a list containing students who have taken both the Systems Analysis and the Project Management courses.

When I select separately 'Systems Analysis' or 'Project Management' it gives me results but not what I need. I need students who have take both courses.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE
FROM STUDENT d,ENROLLMENT f,SECTION g,COURSE h
WHERE d.STUDENT_ID = f.STUDENT_ID AND f.SECTION_ID = g.SECTION_ID AND g.COURSE_NO = h.COURSE_NO 
AND h.DESCRIPTION = 'Systems Analysis' AND h.DESCRIPTION = 'Project Management' 
AND DESCRIPTION NOT IN  
(SELECT m.DESCRIPTION
FROM STUDENT z,ENROLLMENT b,SECTION w,COURSE m
WHERE z.STUDENT_ID = b.STUDENT_ID AND b.SECTION_ID = w.SECTION_ID AND w.COURSE_NO = m.COURSE_NO
AND m.DESCRIPTION = 'Systems Analysis' AND m.DESCRIPTION = 'Project Management')
ORDER BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE;
```

but when I select both 'Systems Analysis' AND 'Project Management' it gives me no rows

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE
FROM STUDENT d,ENROLLMENT f,SECTION g,COURSE h
WHERE d.STUDENT_ID = f.STUDENT_ID AND f.SECTION_ID = g.SECTION_ID AND g.COURSE_NO = h.COURSE_NO 
AND h.DESCRIPTION = 'Systems Analysis' AND h.DESCRIPTION = 'Project Management' 
AND DESCRIPTION NOT IN  
(SELECT m.DESCRIPTION
FROM STUDENT z,ENROLLMENT b,SECTION w,COURSE m
WHERE z.STUDENT_ID = b.STUDENT_ID AND b.SECTION_ID = w.SECTION_ID AND w.COURSE_NO = m.COURSE_NO
AND m.DESCRIPTION = 'Systems Analysis' AND m.DESCRIPTION = 'Project Management')
ORDER BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE;
```

How do I provide a list containing students who have taken both the Systems Analysis and the Project Management courses without giving me no rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE
FROM STUDENT d,ENROLLMENT f,SECTION g,COURSE h
WHERE d.STUDENT_ID = f.STUDENT_ID AND f.SECTION_ID = g.SECTION_ID AND g.COURSE_NO = h.COURSE_NO 
AND h.DESCRIPTION = 'Systems Analysis' 
INTERSECT
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE
FROM STUDENT d,ENROLLMENT f,SECTION g,COURSE h
WHERE d.STUDENT_ID = f.STUDENT_ID AND f.SECTION_ID = g.SECTION_ID AND g.COURSE_NO = h.COURSE_NO 
AND h.DESCRIPTION = 'Project Management'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is something to think about

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
SELECT stud.FIRST_NAME, stud.LAST_NAME, stud.PHONE
FROM STUDENT stud,
inner join ENROLLMENT enr On stud.Student_ID = enr.student_ID
inner join SECTION sec On sec.Section_ID = enr.Section_ID
inner join COURSE syst On syst.course_no = sec.Course_No
inner join COURSE proj On proj.Course_no = sec.Course_No
Where syst.DESCRIPTION = 'Systems Analysis' 
AND proj.DESCRIPTION = 'Project Management' 
ORDER BY stud.FIRST_NAME, stud.LAST_NAME, stud.PHONE
```

if I've rummaged through those aliases correctly, you can have meaningful ones you know. Oh and uses proper join syntax. Trick is to join to course twice, once for systems analysis and once for project management.

PS If there's a sql course in there, I recommend you take it.

Comment: Thank you! I like your style.